# Obj-C method to assign colours to pixels directly?

Tags: objective-c

Currently, I am using SKSpriteKit in order to do all of my graphics stuff in any of my programs. Recently, I’ve been interested in drawing things like the Mandelbrot set, Bifurcation curve, etc.

So to draw these on my screen, I use 1 node per pixel… obviously this means that my program has very low performance with over 100000 nodes on the screen.

I want to find a way of colouring in pixels directly with some command without drawing any nodes. (But I want to stick to Obj-C, Xcode)

Is there some way by accessing Core graphics, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you would use OpenGL ES or Metal to do this.

Here is a tutorial that describes using OpenGL ES shaders with SpriteKit to draw the mandelbrot set:

https://www.weheartswift.com/fractals-xcode-6/